# What layout does new instagram android app use as its gallery image picker?

Tags: android, android-layout, instagram, image-gallery, android-gallery

I am trying to make a gallery image picker like the one used by Instagram on android. I did some research but could not find anything. So any hints or tips on how I can I achieve that layout?

Comment: Use **`uiautomatorviewer`** and find out for yourself what widgets they are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I used a RecyclerView with a FrameLayout on top containing a crop view. Alos there is a scroll listener and touch listener, I achieved the same layout as instagram's image picker. I also used google's gallery app code to load the images much faster. I'll be posting it on github soon and I'll update this post with the link

**EDIT:**
This is a link to a project that does what I wanted.
[Link to project](https://github.com/NodensN/MediaPickerInstagram)

**Update**

Above repo has been removed, a similar repo link below:

https://github.com/luoyiqi/MediaPickerInstagram

Comment: Will you share your solution ? I am doing similar thing too

Comment: Hey will you share your solution ?

Comment: Did you ever post this to github?

Comment: the link is broken . can you edit the answer please ?